# Push notification issue in ios

Tags: ios, push-notification

Hi i am new for push notification and i am working on a project there push notification have been used ,
i understand all code but not [[userInfo objectForKey:@"payload"] objectForKey:@"userId"]] where it can store value in userinfo ??

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*) userInfo {
**if ([self.profileManager.profile.userId isEqualToString:[[userInfo objectForKey:@"payload"] objectForKey:@"userId"]]**) {
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        UIRemoteNotificationType apnsType = [application enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];   
        if(apnsType != UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone) {
            if((apnsType & UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) != 0) {
                [self showNotificationAlert:userInfo];
            }

            if((apnsType & UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge) != 0) {
                NSString* badge = [userInfo valueForKey:@"badge"];  
                application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [badge intValue];
            }
        }
    } else {
        NSString* event = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"payload"] objectForKey:@"event"];
        if ([event isEqualToString:@"QUESTION_ANSWERED"]) {
            [self presentYouAsked];
        } else if ([event isEqualToString:@"QUESTION_ASKED"]) {
            [self presentFriendsAsked];
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's not clear what you are asking. Can you add any more information, or make your question clearer?

Comment: i just want to ask that how to store value in userinfo dictionary and where ?@GregtheIncredulous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `userInfo` dictionary is part of the push notification data that was received.  The line you refer to extracts another dictionary, associated with the key "payload" from the push notification dictionary and then looks for the value associated with the key "userid" in that dictionary.

At a guess that "if" statement it determining whether the push notification that was received applies to the current user on this device.